# MapQuest Geocoding Restrict to One Country Only

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding, mapquest

I've seen this question touched upon for Google Maps, but I'd like to know how to do this in the MapQuest Geocoding API as well.

If I want to limit my API search exclusively to New Zealand, for example, is there a good way to do this?

I've seen this sort of thing in the docs:

```
MQ.geocode({ map: map }).search(address: address, country: 'New Zealand');
```

It doesn't appear to function very well. Seems to be a hint rather than a rule. I want a rule such that if there are no appropriate results in that country, it returns that it couldn't find anything.

I read the docs and it suggested that there is a way to do this, but that calls need to originate from a website with that country's top-level domain?

Any insight into this topic would be greatly appreciated.